IsBadReadPtr Exception access violation reading location only when debugger is attached
This test throws an exception with debugger attached:
SECTION("IsBadReadPtr") {
    auto AllocatedAddress = VirtualAlloc(nullptr, 0x1000, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_NOACCESS);
    IsBadReadPtr(AllocatedAddress, 0x1000);
}


Without the debugger attached it works in debug and release builds. The function IsBadReadPtr is supposed to check if the pointer is accessible.
Any way to fix that? I can't debug other tests and my code when this type of tests throws the exception.

maybe related https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20060927-07/?p=29563

@SimonMourier OK. Well, I understand the problem with those functions but it's still what I want to do and it works just not with the debugger attached.

"it works just not with the debugger attached" - Two issues with this statement: It fabricates a false assessment out of wishful thinking, and then goes ahead to shoot the messenger. "I understand the problem with those functions but it's still what I want" - I'm not following. If you do understand the issue (IsBadXxxPtr should really be called CrashProgramRandomly) why do you complain that you get what you're asking for (unpredictable program behavior)?

@IInspectable "why do you complain that you get what you're asking for (unpredictable program behavior)", one issue with this statement: it fabricates a false assessment out of wishful thinking. I do not ask for the unpredictable program behavior. The function is supposed to return true if the pointer is not readable and false if it's readable. It doesn't do it with the debugger attached. What I'm asking for is what I just stated: so the function return true if the pointer is not readable and false if it's readable. That's all. I don't care about the problems stated in that post.

@IInspectable "(IsBadXxxPtr should really be called CrashProgramRandomly)", two issues with this statement: it doesn't address my question and doesn't provide the solution to my problem.

I understand the question. The issue is that the problem you're trying to address has no practical solution.

@IInspectable no, you don't know what I'm trying to do and why. In this case returning if memory is accessible or not is exactly what I need and want. The problem is that it throws the exception when it shouldn't. And I know about all the other problems discussed in that issue. I don't usually use the IsBadReatPtr to check pointers, I write tests and do TDD, and form correct programs. In this case I need to check if memory is accessible or not but it throws the exception when it shouldn't and only when the debugger is attached.

"it throws the exception when it shouldn't and only when the debugger is attached" - That's not true. Attempting to access inaccessible memory always raises an E_ACCESSDENIED exception. The screenshot indicates that you have configured your debugger to be "noisier" than regular code execution. This exception is (eventually) handled by the API. The fundamental issue here comes down to this: You reading guarantees into an API contract that isn't there. There's no mention that the call will be free of side-effects, but that is your assumption. Assumptions are like LEGO pieces...

"Attempting to access inaccessible memory always raises an E_ACCESSDENIED exception" No, the function is supposed to catch that and just return true for the bad pointer in this case. And it does just that in debug and release builds without the debugger attached. It's just in this case they programmed it so that when the debugger is attached, they breakpoint the debugger but let the program continue, as they specified in the documentation but I didn't go re check it when I got into this problem.

"The screenshot indicates that you have configured your debugger to be "noisier" than regular code execution." Again, no. This is a debugger with default settings out of the box. It's the default behavior for this function, as specified in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-isbadreadptr .

it throw c0000005 in any case. and it is first chance. your debugger configured stop on first chance c0000005. simply remove this option for test. if debugger not handle/stop on first chance - IsBadReadPtr handle it by self

Clearly IsBadReadPtr() is triggering an Access Violation error by reading an inaccessible page.  The Access Violation is handled internally by IsBadReadPtr() so it can return TRUE.
Raymond Chen states as much on his blog:
IsBadXxxPtr should really be called CrashProgramRandomly

Alternatively, it’s possible that your function was called by some code that intentionally passed a pointer to a guard page (or a PAGE_NOACCESS page) and was expecting to receive that guard page exception or access violation exception so that it could dynamically generate the data that should go onto that page. (Simulation of large address spaces via pointer-swizzling is one scenario where this can happen.) Swallowing the exception in IsBadXxxPtr means that the caller’s exception handler doesn’t get a chance to run, which means that your code rejected a pointer that would actually have been okay, if only you had let the exception handler do its thing.

That means the Access Violation has to occur before it can be swallowed. You are simply seeing the debugger reporting the Access Violation to you before IsBadReadPtr() sees it.
This is normal behavior for a debugger!
Simply continue execution and the debugger will pass the Access Violation back to the program's code for normal handling. IsBadReadPtr() will then catch the Access Violation and move on.
This is expected behavior.  There is nothing to fix, as it is not broken.
If you don't want the debugger to report this Access Violation, then you will just have to configure the debugger to ignore it.  Unfortunately, Visual C++'s debugger is not flexible enough to ignore the exception only in this one section of code.  Some other debuggers are more flexible and can do that.

Thanks. Disabling access violation exception in debugger settings works. I think Visual Studio should have checkboxes for this use case: "Break only on unhandled exceptions" and "Don't break on system exceptions that are handled", so it breaks on all the unhandled exceptions but not on this kind of system exceptions that are handled by the system and I can run my tests with a debugger while also still breaking on actual real access violation exceptions.

@KulaGGin an AV is an AV regardless of why it's thrown. Such options as you describe are not possible. At the time the exception is thrown, the debugger doesn't know yet if the exception will be caught or not. Exceptions are handled in stages, and what you are seeing is known as a "first chance" exception, which is designed to let a debugger act first on the exception before the application does. The debugger can ignore the exception, or debug it and possibly modify the conditions that threw it.

In the documentation for the function it says:

If the application is compiled as a debugging version, and the process does not have read access to all bytes in the specified memory range, the function causes an assertion and breaks into the debugger. Leaving the debugger, the function continues as usual, and returns a nonzero value. This behavior is by design, as a debugging aid.

Disabling the Access violation exception in the Debugger Exception Settings fixes the issue.
It's not the proper solution, because now it doesn't breakpoint on all the other access violation exceptions in other places but it's good enough to debug some other tests in this case. The tests that throw this exception and not catch are going to fail, anyway, so it's OK here.
